# PowerShell: how to append text files in Order?

Tags: powershell

```
$inputpath = 1.txt, 2.txt ....
```

Command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $inputpath\* -Include *.txt | Sort-Object -Property Name | Get-Content | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -Path d:\MergedFile.txt -Value "$_" }
```

The Result is a mixed file with duplicated content and in a random order. How can I append multiple files to a new file while considering the order of the source files?

Comment: You appear to be using `$inputpath` as the `-Path` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`, when it isn't really a path, but a listing of files. Are you sure that you shouldn't be using a defined path instead, and using `-Include $inputpath` instead, _or even replacing `-Include` with `-Filter` for a little more speed_. Also I'm not sure that you need `Get-ChildItem` at all, just `Get-Item` should suffice. Additionally, if you have other files named using numeric basenames, you need to be aware that using `Sort-Object -Property Name` will sort your files alphabetically, not numerically.

Comment: To clarify my comment above, I'd suggest perhaps `$inputfiles = @("1.txt", "2.txt", …)` followed by `Get-Item -Path C:\Users\Gill-Bates\Documents\* -Include $inputfiles | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object { Out-File -FilePath D:\mergedFile.txt -InputObject (Get-Content $_) -Append}`. Remembering to modify the `Sort-Object` part according to the information in the already provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you sort on a file's `Name` property, you're sorting *string values*, and the result will be sorted *alphabetically* - which means `10` goes before `9` for example.

If you want to sort by the *numerical value* represented by the string name, you'll have to explicitly tell `Sort-Object` to treat the input values as such:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem ... | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Name -replace '\D' -as [int]} |...
```

In the property expression `{$_.Name -replace '\D' -as [int]}` we take the `Name` property value (like before), remove any non-digit characters, and finally convert the resulting string to an integer.